# Error running Process in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-process

I have the following simple command:

```
 $process = new Process("php /Users/Name/Sites/App/app/../bin/console cache:clear --env=prod");
 $process->run();
```

when I try to run this it gives me:

> string(153) " Parse error: parse error in /Users/Name/Sites/App/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php on line 278 "

What is wrong?

Comment: php version? DependencyInjection component version?

Comment: In my projects `console`'s path is `app/console` instead of `bin/console`. Are you sure about your path?

Comment: Please add the PHP and Symfony versions in your question. As it's written, it's hard to answer to this question because there's too little information.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are using Symfony 3.0 that has "finally" 
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.0/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php#L282

PHP 5.5 and later has support for "finally" in try/catch blocks.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

And looks like your php version is less then 5.5, so upgrade your  php version > 5.5 and it will work

Comment: Specifically, Symfony 3.0 [requires PHP >=5.5.9](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.0/composer.json).

Comment: Yes, exactly, thanks for more presize version http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/requirements.html

Answer (score -1):

```
$process = new Process("php /Users/Name/Sites/App/app/../bin/console cache:clear --env=prod");
$process->run();
```

You should try

```
$process = new Process("php /Users/Name/Sites/App/app/console cache:clear --env=prod");
 $process->run();
```

Because console is in app/ directory  and not in bin/

Comment: You should change the tag therefore